# Autocomplete and mask on a field not working Jquery and MVC

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, maskedinput

I have a field like:

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DivNo)
</div>
```

I am using Autocomplete and maskedinput jquery libraries to format my field and auto complete suggestion from database.

```
$("#DivNo").mask("999 9999");

$("#DivNo").unmask().autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("actionname","ControllerName")',
    minLength: 1
});
```

Now when i enter values into my textbox field, it is not showing autocomplete values as dropdown as i type along. But the mask is working and displaying values in 999 9999 format.Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and found solution so sharing it even after 4 years..
Your input masking is as follows :

```
$("#DivNo").mask("999 9999");
```

So your for example if you type 55 in your input due to masking the input has value as 55_ ____.

**It adds underscore  ( _ )  to the input value instead of 55 which your autocomplete is expecting.**

And obviously your autocomplete will not contain any item which would match the above, hence your autocomplete does not give any suggestion.